# Reverse Proxy on a URL with arguments (Mod Rewrite)

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, reverse-proxy

I need to reverse proxy URLs with the format *test.domain.com/search/web/jsp/apps.jsp?url=https://test-data.domain.com/exec.nsf* to *test2.domain.com/exec.nsf*

With the following code I'm managing to do the first part, however not sure how to mention further the argument **?url=https://test-data.domain.com** in the rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /search/web/jsp/apps\.jsp / [R]
```

With the above code the request test.domain.com/search/web/jsp/apps.jsp?url=https://test-data.domain.com/exec.nsf transforms to test2.domain.com/?url=https://test-data.domain.com/exec.nsf

Update: Solved this way:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=https://[^/]+/([^?]+)
RewriteRule ^/search/web/jsp/apps\.jsp$ https://pge-data2.pedersenandpartners.com/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```